# Python telnet script with two login passwords input?

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

This is the first time I am using python so please help... :)
This telnet script works fine for me if I know the correct password, but the router on `192.168.1.1` will sometimes boot up with the password: `password1` and sometimes with the password: `password2`, and I need the script to be fully automated so passwords need to be read directly from the script because I want to telnet and log to router no matter if the password is the first or the second one.

```
import telnetlib
import time

router = '192.168.1.1'
password = 'password1'
username = 'admin'

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(router)
tn.read_until(b"Login: ")
tn.write(username.encode("ascii") + b"\n")
tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
print("Successfully connected to %s" % router)
tn.write(b"sh ip int bri\n")
time.sleep(2)
print (type("output"))
output = tn.read_very_eager()
#print(output)
output_formatted = output.decode('utf-8')
print(output_formatted)
print("done")`
```

How can I modify this code, to make it try out a second password if the first one was not correct, in order to be successfully logged in via telnet in both cases (`password1` or `password2`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing the first password, `tn.write(password...)`, you need to determine what output corresponds to a correct login. For example, this might be a command prompt ending in "ok >". For an incorrect password, you need to detect output corresponding to another password prompt, for example "Password:" again, or starting again from "Login: ".

You can then use telnetlib's `expect()` method to look simultaneously for these 2 outputs by putting them in a list, eg `["ok >", "Password: "]`. See `pydoc telnetlib`. This method returns a tuple *(index in list, match object, text read till match)*. The only item of interest is the first, the index; it will be 0 if "ok >" was seen, 1 if "Password: " was seen, or -1 if neither was seen by some given timeout. You just need to test this value and proceed appropriately.

```py
index, match, text = tn.expect([b"ok >", b"Password: "], timeout=10)
if index==-1:
 ... # oops, timeout
elif index==1:
 ... # need to send password2
else:
 ... # ok, logged in
```

Note, the strings passed to `expect()` are compiled into regular expressions, so beware of using special characters (see `pydoc re`).